# error in latex file using png file

Tags: graphics

I have used these packages:

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prb,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
     }
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics [height=1.2\textwidth,width=0.9\textwidth] {stem-loop.png}
\caption{ulations.}
\label{stem-loop}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing the `\usepackage` of `graphics` works.

Comment: Is `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphics.` the error you are encountering? Please add the error to your question and reduce the latex document to a minimal version that still shows the error.

Comment: ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   h
l.45 ...eight=1.2 cm,width=0.9 cm] {stem-loop.png}
                                                  
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   h
l.45 ...eight=1.2 cm,width=0.9 cm] {stem-loop.png}
                                                  
these errors is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following combination will run in Pdflatex without error

```
\documentclass[preprint,aps,prb,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{mwe} %added to allow for an example image
%\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig} % do not use outdated epsfig
\usepackage{graphicx} % graphicx loads graphics so use just the one and drop the dvips option 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}
\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{%
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
     }
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics [height=1.2\textwidth,width=0.9\textwidth]{image.png}
\caption{ulations.}
\label{stem-loop}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As a result of comment the compile path was Latex which does not support .png changing the above image.png to image.eps will compile using Latex > ..

The missing step is the need to convert the png to eps first

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in stem-loop.png (no BoundingBo
x).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.48 ...phics[width=0.8\textwidth] {stem-loop.png}
                                                  
? 
<stem-loop.png> [2] (./jpcc-si.aux) )
Output written on jpcc-si.dvi (2 pages, 1444 bytes).
Transcript written on jpcc-si.log.
Now, these kinds of error are showing.

Comment: First run the example above and check it works then replacing image.png with stem-loop.png does it fail if so then it is the png at fault so need a failing example

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in example-image.png (no Boundi
ngBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.48 ...\textwidth,width=0.9\textwidth]{image.png}
                                                  
? 
<example-image.png> [2]
Same error is showing. My compile command are: latex t.tex > dvips t.aux -o t.ps > ps2pdf t.ps t.pdf

Comment: Sorry I ass-umed pdfLaTeX since Latex does not support png it needs to be converted to .eps

Comment: Using pdflatex its working. Thanks

Comment: The loading of `epsfig` should be removed, and also the `dvips` option.

Comment: @egreg thanks from another novice leading … (I had indicated the dvips as a bad option) and accept I was not looking close enough at all settings Thanks edit in progress